# get unique records between two fields from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where my private message are stored which I done with my friends.
[image]

I have table structure as shown in image
Suppose my logged user_id is 1, Now I want show his last five unique conversations with last message of each conversation.

Comment: What is it that you've tried and it broke or did not give the expected results?

Comment: I have tried with `SELECT DISTINCT message_to_uid, message_from_uid FROM `private_msgs` WHERE (message_from_uid = $uid OR message_to_uid = $uid)` this query

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant but working:

```
SELECT m1.*
    FROM private_msgs m1 LEFT OUTER JOIN private_msgs m2 
    ON (m1.message_from_uid=m2.message_from_uid AND m1.message_to_uid=m2.message_to_uid AND m1.message_time<m2.message_time)
WHERE m2.message_id IS NULL AND m1.message_from_uid=$uid
ORDER BY message_time DESC;
```

Add limit to 5 or whatever you want

EDIT. Sorry I didn't notice that UID can be as sender or receiver. Can you publish table with sample data for example here: http://sqlfiddle.com?

Anyway that should to the trick:

```
WHERE m2.message_id IS NULL AND (m1.message_from_uid=$uid OR m1.message_to_uid=$uid)
```

Comment: Nnd Newbie query is working but not as I want. I want show his last five unique conversations. receiver and sender id should be unique.
Suppose I send you message and you send me back that means one conversation but in db table there will be two rows.

Comment: Honestly it's getting hard to achive that in one query. You don't have "conversation_id" so yes, two messages with different dates and sender are treated as different talks. If I were you I would filter it on app level. You can get last five conversations as sender, union it with last five as receiver and then on app level filter the ones that are doubled, leaving the latest one. I'll check later if I can do it with pure sql.

Comment: I've got idea. What if you join table with the second where you replace sender and receiver? I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, long and ugly. You can replace temporary tables as subqueries in one big final query. Explanations are at the end.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 AS
    (SELECT message_id, message_from_uid, message_to_uid, message_time
    FROM private_msgs
    WHERE message_from_uid=$UID)
 UNION 
    (SELECT message_id, message_to_uid, message_from_uid, message_time
    FROM private_msgs
    WHERE message_to_uid=$UID);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t2 AS SELECT * FROM t1;

SELECT m.*
    FROM (t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 
    ON (t1.message_from_uid=t2.message_from_uid AND t1.message_to_uid=t2.message_to_uid AND t1.message_time<t2.message_time)) 
JOIN private_msgs m ON t1.message_id=m.message_id
WHERE t2.message_id IS NULL AND t1.message_from_uid=$UID
ORDER BY t1.message_time DESC;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;
```

t1 temporary table takes all messages where $UID is a sender and union them with messages where $UID is receiver, but puts $UID as sender. In t1 doesn't matter who is sender/receiver. What does matter that these are conversations between $UID and someone else.

t2 is copy of t1, because in MySQL you can't join temporary table with itself.

And finally we do the query. We join t1 and t2, take only newest messages in every conversation and sort it from latest to oldest. As in t1 and t2 sender and receiver are mixed we do the last join with private_msg to get original data.

PS. Sorry for my english, I'm not native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Found among my old code:

```
    select m.*
        from private_messages m
        join user_table s ON m.sender_id = s.id
        join user_table r ON m.receiver_id = r.id
        join (select if(sender_id = $UID, receiver_id, sender_id) as user_id_other,
            max(posted_at) AS date_time_max from private_messages
                where (sender_id = $UID OR receiver_id = $UID)
                group by if(sender_id=$UID, receiver_id, sender_id)
                ) AS t
        on if(m.sender_id = $UID, m.receiver_id, m.sender_id) = user_id_other 
        AND m.posted_at=date_time_max
    where m.sender_id = $UID OR m.receiver_id = $UID
    order by m.posted_at desc
```

Not responsible for result, but this can help. By itself variables must be replaced, I did not modify the code very much, as you can see. But this piece of... code... worked.

In your case smths like:

```
select m.*
    from YOUR_MESSAGES_TABLE m
    --- OPTIONAL: join YOUR_USER_TABLE s ON m.message_from_uid = s.id
    --- OPTIONAL: join YOUR_USER_TABLE r ON m.message_to_uid = r.id
    join (select if(message_from_uid = $YOUR_USER_ID, message_to_uid, message_from_uid) as user_id_other,
        max(message_time) AS date_time_max from YOUR_MESSAGES_TABLE
            where (message_from_uid = $YOUR_USER_ID OR message_to_uid = $YOUR_USER_ID)
            group by if(message_from_uid=$YOUR_USER_ID, message_to_uid, message_from_uid)
            ) AS t
    on if(m.message_from_uid = $UID, m.message_to_uid, m.message_from_uid) = user_id_other 
AND m.message_time=date_time_max
where m.message_from_uid = $UID OR m.message_to_uid = $UID
order by m.message_time desc limit 5
```

Test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f66fd8/4